# objective c getting substring after and before dot

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a string like 112.1 or 102.2 etc now i want to get the substring before dot and after the dot using objective c, means i want to get 2 substrings like this 112 and 1. please guide. Regards Saad.

Comment: Have you checked the NSString reference https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html for the solution ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try the following:

```
NSArray *arrayWithTwoStrings = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
```

Using this method you'll get NSArray containing string components that were separated by "." string, that is "112" and "1" for "112.1" string. After that you can access them using array's `objectAtIndex:` method.

P.S. Note also that if you're going to use numeric values of those strings there might be better solution

Comment: Thanx Vladimir, but can u explain a little your answer please.

Comment: Thanx Vladimir, that explains a lot.

Answer (score 13):

```
NSString *str = yourstr;  
NSArray *Array = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];        
NSString *t = [Array objectAtIndex:0];  
NSString *t1 = [Array objectAtindex:1];
```

Comment: The last line should be "NSString *t1 = [Array objectAtIndex:1];" with a capital "I" in "Index"

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray* components = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
```